# Linkedin Share Button FORM_INVALID Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, share, linkedin-api

I have a problem that LinkedIn share button suddenly stopped working. (It used to work.)  It is created by [Button Generator](http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-plugin-generator).

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
 lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="right"></script>
```

And it loads a popup with all content and images without problems and it loads LinkedIn users if I want share it with specific person without problem.

But the problem is that share button on the popup doesn't do anything when it is clicked.

On the Firebug console, it is written...

```
<WSResponse>


  <responseInfo>FORM_INVALID</responseInfo>
  <responseMsg></responseMsg>
  <jsonPayLoad></jsonPayLoad>

      <formErrors>
        { globalError : '',
          inlineErrors: {

              'messageSubject-shareForm' : 'The text you provided is too long (the maximum length is 150 characters, your text contains 152 characters).'
          }
        }
      </formErrors>
</WSResponse>
```

Comment: does the same thing happen if you re-create the script and re-add it to whatever you're working on?

Comment: It does even if I recreate the script or use a plugin. Even if it is  long/short title or content or url. Still same issue

Comment: Surely this is your error right here: `'messageSubject-shareForm' : 'The text you provided is too long (the maximum length is 150 characters, your text contains 152 characters).` Validation maybe?

Comment: i was assuming it couldn't be that obvious...?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an evolving question.  To be clear, the [Original Linkedin Developer Share Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share) is just a blank page, and you can find a newer one here: [Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin).

*The `title` ("subject"?), `summary`, and `source` parameters are no longer supported by LinkedIn.*

Naturally, the new documentation doesn't mention any other field but: `url`.  So, if you want to share, it's as simple as...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

If you are interested in a regularly maintained github project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]